# Jquery validate from with non require fields in grails from

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

I got a form, input field and select box. Now I'd like to check if people input to the field, they also need to check the value from select box before submitting the form. Otherwise just submit.

Here my code:

```
<g:form action="saveInfo2" id="applicantForm">
    <input id="checkDL1" type="text" name="forJobsRequiringUseOfAMotorVehicleDlNo1"/>
    <select id="checkState1">
        <option value=''></option>
        <option value='1'></option>
        <option value='2'></option>
    </select>
</g>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
$(function () {
$("#submit").click(function ()  //submit button click
    {
     var inputval=$('#checkDL1').val();
     var selval=$('#checkState1').val(); 
         if(inputval=="")
            {
                alert("pllease enter text field");
                return false;
         }   
         if(selval==0)
            { 
                alert("pllease select option");
                    return false;
            }
        else{ 
        return true;
        }

        });   
        });  
    </script> 

<g:form action="saveInfo2" id="applicantForm">
    <input id="checkDL1" type="text"  name="forJobsRequiringUseOfAMotorVehicleDlNo1"/>
    <select id="checkState1">
        <option value='0'>select</option>
        <option value='1'>hi</option> 
        <option value='2'>hello</option>

    </select>
        <input  type="submit" id="submit" name="submit"/>
</g>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k6jbu/